# iOS 8 Widget Alignment Issue

Tags: ios, widget, ios8

I'm having trouble aligning an iOS 8 widget all the way to the left. It seems that setting the x origin to 0 still keeps a certain amount of space between the left edge of the screen and my first view.

I'm not sure how Evernote does this, but it seems that they have it figured out. Any suggestions? I also tried setting the x position programmatically to no success.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the answer:

```
    // MARK: NCWidgetProviding protocol methods

func widgetMarginInsetsForProposedMarginInsets(defaultMarginInsets: UIEdgeInsets) -> UIEdgeInsets
    {
        return UIEdgeInsetsZero
    }
```

Comment: This only works if you don't want to align with the widget icon or title like many do. And you should according to Apple docs.